# Floating Nodes in PSpice

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, cmos, pspice, cascode

Hello I am designing a folded cascode amplifier with only long channel devices. I believe I have set up the schematic correctly but I am getting the following errors:
ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node VB1 is floating

ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node VBB is floating

ERROR(ORPSIM-15143): Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving V_V6. You may break the loop by adding a series resistance
Attached will be the script and schematic, any help would be great thank you

```
* source PROJECT1_42000
C_C2         0 VOB  1p  TC=0,0 
V_V4         N28655 0 2.1
V_V3         VINB N28655 DC {-Vin/2} AC -1 
C_C1         0 VOA  1p  TC=0,0 
V_V2         0 N28655 DC 0 AC 1 
E_E1         VOCM_EXISTING N28505 VOA 0 0.5
M_M2         VDD VB4 VB4 VDD AMI06P  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=19.5u  
+ AD={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ AS={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*19.5u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*19.5u+2.4u}     
M_M16         VDD VB4 Y VDD AMI06P  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=19.5u  
+ AD={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ AS={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*19.5u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*19.5u+2.4u}     
M_M3         VB2 VB2 0 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
M_M7         N29635 VB1 0 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
M_M17         Y VB2 VOB VDD AMI06P  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=19.5u  
+ AD={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ AS={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*19.5u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*19.5u+2.4u}     
M_M10         VOB VB3 N29451 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
E_E3         VBB VB1 VOCM_EXISTING VOCM 0.5
M_M6         X 0 N29635 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
E_E2         N28505 0 VOB 0 0.5
I_I1         VDD VB3 DC 37uA  
M_M13         VOA VB3 N29447 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
M_M1         VB3 VB3 VB2 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
M_M8         Y VINB N29635 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
V_V5         VDD 0 5Vdc
M_M14         X VB2 VOA VDD AMI06P  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=19.5u  
+ AD={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ AS={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*19.5u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*19.5u+2.4u}     
M_M12         N29447 VB2 0 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
M_M15         VDD VB4 X VDD AMI06P  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=19.5u  
+ AD={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ AS={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*19.5u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*19.5u+2.4u}     
M_M9         N29635 VBB 0 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
V_V1         VOCM 0 DC 2.5 AC 1 
M_M4         VB4 VB2 VB2 VDD AMI06P  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=19.5u  
+ AD={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ AS={19.5u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*19.5u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*19.5u+2.4u}     
M_M11         N29451 VB1 0 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
M_M5         VB2 VB1 0 0 AMI06N  
+ L=1.2u  
+ W=12.45u  
+ AD={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ AS={12.45u*1.2u}  
+ PD={2*12.45u+2.4u}  
+ PS={2*12.45u+2.4u}     
R_R1         VB3 VDD  0 TC=0,0 
.PARAM  vin=0
```

[image]

Comment: Near transistor M6, you have shorted Vina to ground accidentally. Fix that and try again

Answer (score 1):

Near transistor M6, you have shorted vina to ground accidentally. This is causing the voltage source loop.

Regarding the floating nodes vbb & vb1, the component E3 is defining the difference between vbb & vb1 i.e., vbb-vb1 is defined but that is not sufficient.
For eg., if vbb-vb1 = 0V then, vbb = vb1 = 1V also satisfies the equation, vbb = vb1 = 2V also satisfies the equation and so on. So, you have not defined vbb and vb1 sufficiently w.r.t the common ground which is why the simulator says that it is a floating node.